# Camel Netty not sending from a file to UDP

Tags: java, udp, apache-camel, netty

I can successfully read from a file and send the contents over UDP using Camel Netty, but only if I modify the message contents in a processor before sending over UDP.

I have a simple class to demonstrate, which has two camel routes:

1. Read a file from 'inbox' directory (the test file I'm using is small - less than 50 bytes), write it to 'outbox' directory, and send it over UDP
2. Read from UDP and simply process the message (in this example, just print out some lines)

Writing the file to outbox always seems to work (implying to me that the camel wiring is OK), but sending over UDP only seems to work if I manually update the content of the message. The code is below, and I have tried the following:

- Code as is (with the Processor commented out)

  - the file is written to outbox (with content matching the input file)
  - nothing received over UDP
- Processor uncommented, just doing in.setBody("blah");

  - the file is written to outbox (with content of "blah")
  - the message "blah" received over UDP
- Processor uncommented, just doing in.setBody(in.getBody());

  - the file is written to outbox (with content matching the input file)
  - nothing received over UDP
- Processor uncommented, just doing System.out.println("Read [" + in + "] from file");

  - the file is written to outbox (with content matching the input file)
  - nothing received over UDP
  - the line "Read [test.txt] from file" is printed multiple times

**Update:**

- Processor uncommented, doing in.setBody(in.getBody() + " ... Blah");

  - the file is written, although the content is "GenericFile[test.txt] ... Blah" (the input file name was test.txt) rather than the actual file content
  - received the data over UDP (again, "GenericFile[test.txt] ... Blah", rather than the actual file content

Code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("file://inbox?noop=true")
//                .process(new Processor() {
//                    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
//                      Message in = exchange.getIn();
//                        in.setBody("blah");
//                        in.setBody(in.getBody());
//                        System.out.println("Read [" + in + "] from file");
//                    }
//                })
                .to("file://outbox")
                .to("netty:udp://localhost:9999/");
            }
        });

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("netty:udp://localhost:9999/")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                        Message in = exchange.getIn();
                        System.out.println("Got [" + in.getBody() + "] over UDP");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How big are your files? There's a maximum payload limit of around 64K in a UDP message. I'm not sure what happens if you try to write a bigger buffer than that. Also large UDP messages will be fragmented by the underlying transport (about 1460 bytes per ethernet frame). If one of those fragments is lost on the network the entire UDP message will be discarded.

Comment: @johnstlr - the file size is small for the test file I'm using - less than 50 bytes, just a few lines of text. I've added another test case in an attempt to prove the size isn't the issue - but this has just led to even more confusing behaviour... (see the update in the question)

Comment: Check the return type from getIn().getBody(). I'm not that familiar with Camel but is it returning a File object as a reference, rather than the actual file body? The ETL examples on the camel website reference a convertBodyTo(..) step which may load the file. Alternatively you may need to load the file manually in your processor.